# Running Multiple Remote Commands Consecutively Through Matlab system()

Tags: linux, matlab, ssh

I'd like to execute multiple commands consecutively using a matlab system call. I would first like to ssh into a remote machine then run a program on that machine. After the program starts I would like to then enter another command into this program's console. Here is what I would like to do in code:

```
system('ssh othermachine')
system('command on other machine')
%%WAIT FOR PROGRAM TO START RUNNING ON OTHER MACHINE
system('run command on other machine')
```

The problem is that Matlab will hang on the first system call and won't proceed to the next system call until the process form the first is exited. Is there a way around this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prologue: Your problem  is general and not just related to matlab.

When you want to run remote commands via ssh, they have to be issued in the ssh call. In a (linux) shell, you'd have

```
$ ssh remotemachine command1
```

for a single command. Hence, using a matlab `system` call you would have

```
>> system('ssh remotemachine command1').
```

When you want multiple commands to be executed sequentially, in a shell you'd write

```
$ ssh remotemachine "command1; command2"
```

i.e., in matlab, you'd write something like

```
>> system('ssh remotemachine "command1; command2"').
```

In general, is way more elegant to group your commands in a shell script, say `script.sh`, and pipe it in the ssh call

```
$ cat script.sh | ssh remotemachine
```

which, in matlab shell, sounds like

```
>> system('cat script.sh | ssh remotemachine').
```

There are a number of flags you can add in order to specify which behavior you want (e.g. in terms of session detachment/background execution, output collection,... [look e.g. here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ssh.htm)).